# make buttons stick at the bottom of a card with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

So I have a webpage with cards for different size screens the cards contain an image, an h2, a p, 2 buttons and a p that tells how many words the article that you receive when clicking the Read button contains. When I use it for tablet or where there are 2 or 4 cards beside one an other i run into a problem the buttons and the word element don't stick to the bottom of the card if one h2 needs rows to fit than the other cards.

I have tried wrapping the h2 and p in one element, the buttons and the second p in one and do space between on their parent.
I have tried fiddling with hight but without success.
This should be done with pure css and no JS.

Here are the HTML and CSS for one card:

```
<article class="article-card">
            <img
              src="https://picsum.photos/id/96/700/800"
              alt="img"
              class="article-card__image"
            />
            <div class="article-card__content">
              <h2 class="article-card__content__header">PlayStation 7</h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Exercitationem aliquid ratione debitis! Eos nam tempora,
                deleniti sed et atque pariatur!
              </p>
              <div class="article-card__content__buttons">
                <button class="article-card__content__buttons__read-button">
                  Read
                </button>
                <button class="article-card__content__buttons__share-button">
                  Share
                </button>
                <p>316 words</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
```

```
.article-card {
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgb(207, 207, 207);
}

.article-card__image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
}

.article-card__content {
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.article-card__content__header {
    padding: 40px 0px 25px 0px;
}

.article-card__content__buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.article-card__content__buttons > p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
}

.article-card__content__buttons__read-button,
.article-card__content__buttons__share-button {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.article-card__content__buttons__read-button:hover,
.article-card__content__buttons__share-button:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

Add to `.article-card`

```
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column; 
justify-content: space-between;
```

And then put a div around `img h2 p` at the same level as `.article-card__content__buttons`